# Verificação e criação de pastas em python

Tags: python

Olá,

Estou criando um código que deve verificar se uma pasta existe, se ela não existir o código deve criá-la e então prosseguir, caso contrário, apenas segue com o fluxo.

Já tentei com If e While porém não obtive sucesso. Na maioria das vezes ele cria a pasta que eu desejo porém me retorna o erro "Não foi possível criar uma pasta já existente". Para que isto ocorra deve haver um loop que não estou conseguindo identificar, podem me ajudar?

Segue as duas formas que tentei abaixo:

MODO 1:

```
if username and password != None:

    while os.path.exists('C:\ Backup') == False:

        makedirs("C:\ Backup\ ")

        if os.path.exists('C:\ Backup') == True:
            break

else:
    print "nao foi possivel logar"

            #for ip in radius:

            #gravar = open(ip+".txt", "w")
            #gravar.write("Configuração")
            #gravar.close()
```

MODO 2:

```
if username and password != None:

    if pass os.path.exists('C:\ Backup') == False:

        makedirs("C:\ Backup\ ")

        else:

            for ip in radius:

            gravar = open(ip+".txt", "w")
            gravar.write("Configuração")
            gravar.close()

else:
    print "nao foi possivel logar"
```

PS: Talvez seja algo simples que não consegui identificar, não tenho muita experiência com programação mas estou tentando melhorar. So, i'm sorry.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
import os.path

# nao tenho bem a certeza se e isto que quer, nao sera: if username == 'USERNAME CORRETO' and password == 'PASSWORD CORRETA': ?
if username != None and password != None:
    pasta = 'C:\Backup'
    if os.path.isdir(pasta): # vemos de este diretorio ja existe
        print ('Ja existe uma pasta com esse nome!')
    else:
        os.mkdir(pasta) # aqui criamos a pasta caso nao exista
        print ('Pasta criada com sucesso!')

    # prosseguir com o codigo aqui, nesta linha onde esta o cardinal (hash)

else:
    print 'nao foi possivel logar'
```

Comment: Obrigado Miguel, me ajudou muito!

Comment: De nada @CristhianMiguel. Ainda bem que resolveu